# add data from a file into a class dict

Tags: python, class, dictionary, exec

i've wrote a class dict and built a data file based on the blue print of that class dict

```
for num in range(0, 1)
    some_dict.update({f"id_{num}: copy.deepcopy(SomeClass.__init__.__kwdefaults__)})
```

then overwrote default values with actual information when available.

now i want to load that data file into the class dict in order to call its data by keys and values so i can perform further calculations with them.

class dict in main.py:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, *, a=None, b=[]):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

file.py with the following line structure:

```
id_1 = SomeClass{'a': 'x', 'b': ['c', 'd']}
id_2 = SomeClass{'a': 'y', 'b': ['e', 'f']}
```

i want to load the file and put it into the class dict as if i wrote:

```
id_1 = SomeClass(a='x', b= ['c', 'd'])
```

directly into main.py.

first i picked apart the lines in file.py in a for loop with a mix of .split() and .replace() methods to get to the keys 'a' and 'b', which are still strings at this point.
then i tried to eval() or exec() them in order to turn the strings into reference names

```
with open(r"file.py", mode="r", errors="ignore") as file:
    line_count = 0
    for line in file:
        split_line1 = line.split("'")
        split_line2 = line.split("[")[1].split("]")
        a_key = split_line1[1]
        a_value = split_line1[3]
        b_key = split_line1[5]
        b_value = split_line2[0]
        f"id_{line_count} = " + SomeClass(eval(a_key) + "=" + a_value, eval(b_key) + "=" + b_value)
        line_count += 1
```

but i end up with a:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

i already ran into the NameError problem while building file.py and had to work around it. i don't see how to get to my goal without the use of eval() or exec() and consequently running into the NameError and if you can't feed information to class dicts from files i fail to see the use of class dicts.

Comment: "first i... [long description of code]" We cannot debug your code based off a description. Please show the *actual code* you used in order to try doing this.

Comment: Why are you doing things this way to begin with?

Comment: @juanpa arrivillaga i choose a class with kwdefaults over a regular dict because its more flexible down the line. if you know a better way to approach this i'm open for suggestions.@Karl Knechtel added the code, the "eval(a_key) and eval(b_key) throw the NameErrors.

Comment: No, I mean, why are you trying to save/load from a file like that? Why not JSON? Or pickle?

Comment: @juanpa arrivillaga primarily cause i'm not familiar with either but if it would make the task easier i'll look into them.